# phonegap javascript files accessibility

Tags: javascript, cordova, browser

Are the javascript files in a phonegap app on a mobile device accessible/visible to the user like they are in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap works by extending and wrapping common classes of the iOS / Android SDKs. Since the html files are wrapped by phonegap code, i dont think you can view/access its html or javacript files like normal desktop browsers.

Checkout this [link](http://hiediutley.com/2011/03/14/phonegap-tutorial-series-1-project-structure-and-internals/)

And also check this [link](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/05/comparing-titanium-and-phonegap.html) ( How PhoneGap Works )